# Are there any cases when submatch(0) would not work in vim regexp replace?

Tags: regex, vim

I have roughly the following source data, over which I am attempting to perform a global replace via vim's regexp search and replace:

```
      "text": [{
        "uid": "...",
        "left": 50,
        "top": 715,
        "minSize": 60,
        "maxSize": 70,
        "width": "345px",
        "align": "center",
        "font": "...",
        "forbidden": "",
        "border": true,
        "printType": 0
      }
```

My search/replace string looks like:

`:%s/"left": \(\d\+\)/"left": \=submatch(1)*0.66/g`

Effectively, I am attempting to reduce the `"left"` property to 66% of its current value, in all cases.

Unfortunately, the resulting string becomes:

```
      "text": [{
        "uid": "...",
        "left": =submatch(1)*0.66,
        "top": 715,
        "minSize": 60,
        "maxSize": 70,
        "width": "345px",
        "align": "center",
        "font": "...",
        "forbidden": "",
        "border": true,
        "printType"
```

So, instead of getting `"left": 33` I get `"left": =submatch(1)*0.66`.

At first, I thought it was because I was using `=submatch(0)`. However, switching to `=submatch(0)` didn't fix the problem, and simply returned `=submatch(0)` in the replaced string.

Would there be cases in which the expression wouldn't be evaluated correctly?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `\=` needs to be the first thing in the replacement.

Comment: You're right, I just tried it and that certainly "worked", but obviously doesn't do what I want! Is there a way to use `submatch...` without having `\=` be the first thing?

Comment: Its all or nothing. I answered with a possible solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using expression in the replacement the replacement must start with `\=` and then the rest is evaluated as an expression. In your case you just escaped the equals sign.

The easiest way to do this would be use `\zs` to start the match right before the number

```
:%s/"left": \zs\d\+/\=submatch(0) * 0.66
```

And then use `submatch(0)` for the whole match, which in this case is only the number.